# Basic 404 setup not working

Tags: error, 404, error-handling

I look at past Q & A about this, but am still perplexed.

- Not logged in to CP or frontend
- I have a simple template called 404.twig which resides in the **templates** folder
- I can access the template directly at domain.com/404
- This is a multi-site Craft install
- Hit an invalid URL, like domain.com/oasdoasd
- See this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `devMode` is on, you will always see the above exception page. Turn it off to see your 404 page, or just navigate directly to the template, e.g. http://example.com/404

More here: https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#handling-exceptions-on-the-frontend

Comment: Thanks @andrew.welch. I've read your article, it's very helpful. However, I have this:


return [
    // Global settings
    '*' => [

Comment: I have read your article, thanks, it's very helpful. Turns out this was a PEBMAK problem, I had my devMode statement in the wrong place.